# Why do I get an error (Notice: Undefined index) when I try to echo a value from my database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database with a field named 'registered'. Its value is either 0 or 1. Now what I want to do is to echo the value of the registered field based on the LRN that I specified (I also have a 'LRN' field).

For example I entered the LRN 123, and its corresponding 'registered' value is 1, then I want to echo 1.

However, I get an error when I use this code:

```
$lrn = $_POST['lrn'];
//connect to database
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "php24sql", "hJQV8RTe5t", "smithside");
$query2 = "SELECT registered FROM contacts WHERE LRN = '$lrn'";
$query2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$registered = '';
$registered = (int) $_GET['registered'];
echo $registered;
```

The error is:

> Notice: Undefined index: registered in C:\xampp\htdocs\System_CompA2\content\register.php
>   And then the echoed value is always 0.

Comment: If you need the value of registered from the query, I don't see you fetching the result set from the query. Also since you are getting the undefined index error it is clear that the `$_GET` parameter is  not set.

Comment: You're not fetching the value from the query after executing. And you're echoing the value from a $_GET instead of the result of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the value of registered from the database, you need to fetch the result set array from the database. You need to add something like this:

```
$query2 = "SELECT registered FROM contacts WHERE LRN = '$lrn'";
$query2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
$registered = $row['registered'];
echo $registered;
```

That should get you the value.

Comment: Ok thanks it worked. Sorry I don't know a lot of php because I am just doing self study since my school didn't teach us enough php but wants us to pass this for a requirement.